# High-Fidelity Mocks: How many per day/hour/average?

Tags: gui-design, design, mockup

Fellow UI/UX Designers,

Is this an impossible question to answer? How many high-fidelity mocks should your employer expect per hour/day/average etc.?

> No two mocks are the same, some small features can take 10-20 minutes
>   to draft, but some require HOURS/DAYS of research before creating a
>   production-ready mockup.

I've looked around and cannot find a good answer for this (if one even exists).

I currently have 4 days to complete over 100 mocks, and I really want to explain how impossible/ridiculous this request is with some data. Thanks

Comment: How did you agree to this? Fidelity is the last thing anyone should be concerned with if you want to generate a lot of mock ups in a short amount of time.

Comment: Luke, I didn't agree to it per se, it's just what needs to happen to meet development deadlines.

Comment: Fast, good or cheap? Pick two. Four days = fast. That means low m fidelity mocks in maybe half the quantity you suggested, if you're working on nothing else. I'd love to know where they come up with kind of project estimate.

Answer (score 4):

This one probably needs a little more context to give an helpful answer. To me, saying "over 100 mocks" already sounds a weird request: how do you know how many? What documentation / brief do you have? Where do the number comes from?

For the sake of the argument I tried to do some math: 100 mocks in 4 days means 25 per day; suppose we have an eight hour working day when we do nothing but mock: that would be roughly 3 every 60 minutes, 20 minutes per mock. No interruption, no discussion, no iterations, just ruthless production.

If your clients are sensitive to numbers maybe you can start from this and then guide them to a better understanding

I think that much depends on what you have to build, what are the expectations on the results and what you are given as a preparatory work. However, it would be interesting to know if others have a "mock production rate" and on which basis.

Comment: Hey Lili, you are absolutely right, I should have added more context, this is a redesign of a VERY complex application, and it includes things such as the entire registration flow/validation/errors/password reset/email verification steps, and then the inner applications screens (Dashboard/Inbox/Order Screens etc.) including profile/account settings/security... Basically, think of it as if you had to redesign EVERY screen of Microsofts HealthVault to match a completely different UI framework like Google Material, and also refine some outdated features/designs.

Comment: Then it is both outlandish towards you and a disservice to themselves to request a 100 mockups with no regard to quality. For a complex funnel I already take 2-3 days to make ONE happy flow. That's maybe 3-4 screens with just the best case scenario content. There's a lot of things to consider here. You can't make a good quality process with so little time no matter how skilled you are. For your own sanity, you should bring this up and try to set some more healthy deadlines. It'll be better for the product too..